# How to use keyframes on a specific seection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a fixed header and I'm using keyframes to change it's color. However, this purpose is only to be used on a CSS slider which is in a specific section, call it `section0`. Now, the problem with that solution is that when I scroll to another section the fixed header effect remains active and I can't find a way around this.

I realize that the use of Javascript should be used to make the keyframe work on only that specific `section0` but I have no idea how to do it.

Here's my html code and the accompanying Keyframe css for the animation:

```
<header>
  <nav id="headNav">
    <ul>
        <li data-menuanchor="home" class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <span>|</span>
        <li data-menuanchor="collections"><a href="#collections">Collections</a></li>
        <span>|</span>
        <li data-menuanchor="showroom"><a href="#showroom">Showroom</a></li>
        <span>|</span>
        <li data-menuanchor="contact"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <span>|</span>
        <li data-menuanchor="about"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>

<main id="fullPage">
<div class="section" id="section0">
  <!--Should only be animated here -->
  <div id="slider">
    <figure>
        <img src="images/eg1.jpg" alt="" title="" />
        <img src="images/eg2.jpg" alt="" title="" />
        <img src="images/eg3.jpg" alt="" title="" />        
      <img src="images/eg4.jpg" alt="" title="" />
      <img src="images/eg5.jpg" alt="" title="" /> 
    </figure>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="section1">
  <!--Some stuff here. Header should not be animated here -->
</div>

<div id="section2">
  <!--Some stuff here. Header should not be animated here -->
</div>
</main>
```

Here's the CSS that animates the header:

```
@keyframes colorful {
0% {  color: #162c83}
20% { color:  #162c83}
25% { color:#FFFF00}
45% { color:#FFFF00}
50% { color:#F00}
70% { color:#F00}
75% { color:#FFFF00}
95% { color:#FFFF00}
100% { color:#162c83}
}

header {animation : 15s colorful infinite}
header nav a{animation : 15s colorful infinite}
```

I'm not sure how to make the Javascript to work only for `section`0, that is use the keyframes only on `section0`.Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a js library like [Waypoints.js](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/) to add a specific class to the slider. Add the animation to that class. With waypoints you can see if a div is over a specific section and then apply the appropriate class to it. You can do as such:

```
$('.section1').waypoint(function(){
        $('#headNav').addClass('color-header');
  });
 $('.section2').waypoint(function(){
        $('#headNav').removeClass('color-header');
 });
```

Your css will look something like this then.

```
.color-header
{
   animation-name:colourful
}
```

**Edit**
An other way about this: You could attach an event-handler on your list-item of your navigation menu. Then you could check if the item is the 'home' item. If it its, add the class colourful to the header. If not, remove the class.If you copy paste this, make sure to add the id: 'navlist' to your ul.

```
    var menu = $('header');
    $('ul#navlist li').on('click',function(){
        var link = $(this).data('menuanchor');
        console.log(link)
        if(link === 'home')
        {
          menu.addClass('colourful');
        }
        else
        {
          menu.removeClass('colourful');
        }
  });
```

Your Css should like this:

```
 .colourful
 {
   animation-name:color;
   animation-duration:15s;
 }

 @keyframes color
 {
  0% {  color: #162c83}
  20% { color:  #162c83}
  25% { color:#FFFF00}
  45% { color:#FFFF00}
  50% { color:#F00}
  70% { color:#F00}
  75% { color:#FFFF00}
  95% { color:#FFFF00}
  100% { color:#162c83}
 }
```

Comment: I tried to use the solution, it doesn't seem to work. :/

Comment: Do you have your website online somewhere? Are you sure you implemented the script etc. correct? If you have a link I'll have a look at it.

Comment: Here's the link: http://sabirmb.com/Parallax/
The effect should work only on the slider but since it's a fixed header it's working on all other sections. The problem is I need to use JS to make this work only on the slider. So I guess it should be trying to get the JS to use the keyframes only on the slider section.

Comment: hmm, I don't see the waypoints.js in your script tags or called in your main.js? Can you add waypoints.js to your site? I'll try to mess with the script a bit to get it to work.

Comment: Basically I loaded the waypoint and added the script in your answer in my '<body>' but it didn't work. I guess I then removed the script from the site but the waypoint.js is still there

Comment: I made an alternative suggestions in my original answer. It's easier since you have vertical scrolling disabled.

Comment: If you check the link now, I made the changes as you said, still doesn't work for some reason. I think this CSS is making it not work but when I remove the following CSS no effect appears:

>header {animation : 15s colorful infinite}
>header nav a{animation : 15s colorful infinite}

Comment: I made a small mistake in my script, please adjust (the tags around menuanchor' on the second line). Also remove the colourful animation from your header in your css.

Comment: I see you're playing around with it. The selector works fine. Add the colourful class to the header in your html. That way the animation starts from the beginning. You can also see in your console that it logs the correct name of the link you clicked. I think there is some mistake in your css of the animation.

Comment: I'm following the website, can you add the line again with the console.log?

Comment: Added. I checked it and according to your code, the log shows up when home link is clicked but no effect happens. Also, I'm trying to make it happen without clicking. Just when page is loaded or user is on section0(home) it works

Comment: Ok, there was a typo in animation-duration (I spelled it as animation-duration). Anyway, try adjusting the name as I did in the answer (animation name to color, same with keyframe) and adjust the typo ;)

Comment: If you add the class to your header in your html, then it would work from page load. Problem is now that for some reason the animation won't load.

Comment: Now on clicking Home it works, but then it goes back to the same initial problem of it having the effect on every section and not only home